# How can if statement be used within echo

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have to  check the results  that are coming from fetch array, I am using `else if` or `if` to get the remarks. But I do not know how to use it with in echo, When I run this code all the remarks statements come in same form as written in code.

In this I have to  check the results  that is coming from fetch array, so for this I am using else if or if to get the remarks..but i am do not know how to use it with in echo. When I run this code all the remarks statements come in same form as written in code

**Code:**

```
     <?php
    $answer = '';
      include('config.php');
      if(isset($_GET["results"]))
     $answer = $_GET["results"];
      $id = $_GET["idk"];
      switch ($answer) 
      {  
        case 'Nursery':
        $qqqs = mysql_query("select * from result where u_id='$id' AND sc='Nursery' ");
        $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($qqqs);
        $a=$rows['u_id'];
        $b=$rows['name'];
        $c=$rows['fname'];
        $d=$rows['reg'];
        $e=$rows['sc'];
        $f=$rows['ss'];
        $g=$rows['se'];
        $h=$rows['e1'];
        $i=$rows['u1'];
        $j=$rows['m1'];
        $k=$rows['s1'];
        $l=$rows['ss1'];
        $m=$rows['i1'];
        $n=$rows['e2'];
        $o=$rows['u2'];
        $p=$rows['e3'];
        $pp=$rows['u3'];
        $pic=$rows['picture'];
        $total=$h+$i+$j+$k+$l+$m+$n+$o+$p;
        $totals=230;

        $res = ( $totals / $total) * 100;

        // 0 digit after the decimal point
        $res = round($res); // 67

        // 1 digit after the decimal point
        $res = round($res, 1); // 66.7

        // 2 digits after the decimal point
        $res = round($res, 2); // 66.67


        echo "<html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
        <table align='center' border='4' bgcolor='white' width='500' class='table table-bordered'>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor='orange' colspan='4'><h2 align='center'>Leads Grammar School</h2><p align='center'>Babar Road, Kirri Jamandan, Multan</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor='yellow' colspan='4'><h2 align='center'>Monthly Test Feb-March</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan='2'><img src='images/$pic' width='100px' height='100px' align='right'></td>
         </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align='right'>Student's Name</td>

        <td colspan='3'>$b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align='right'>Father's Name</td>
        <td colspan='3'> $c</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align='right'>Registration</td>
        <td colspan='3'>$d</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align='right'>Student Class</td>
        <td colspan='3'>$e</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align='right'>Exams</td>
        <td colspan='3'>$f</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor='gray'>
        <th>Subject Name</th>
        <th>Marks</th>
        <th>Obtained Marks</th>
        <th>Grades</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr><td>English(Writing)</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td> $h</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr ><td>Urdu(Writing)</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>$i</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr ><td>Math(Writing)</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td> $j</td>

        </tr>
        <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>General Knowledge</th></tr>
        <tr>
        <tr ><td>Science</td>
        <td>10</td>

        <td> $k</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr ><td>S.Studies</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$l</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <tr ><td>Islamiat</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$m</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>Poems</th></tr>
        <tr>
        <tr ><td>English </td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td> $n</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <tr ><td>Urdu</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>$o</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>Book Reading</th></tr>
        <tr>
        <tr><td>English </td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$p</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <tr >
        <td>Urdu</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>$pp</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
         <td><h1>Total Marks</h1></td>
         <td>230</td>
         <td>$total</td>
         <td>$res</td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td><h2>Remarks</h2></td>
         <td colspan='3'>
         if(91=<$res<=100)
         {
            echo 'Exceptional';
         } 
        else  if(81=<$res<=90)
         {
            echo 'Excellent';
         } 
          else  if(71=<$res<=80)
         {
            echo 'Very Good';
         } 
          else  if(61=<$res<=70)
         {
            echo 'Good';
         } 
          else  if(51=<$res<=60)
         {
            echo 'Fair';
         } 
          else  if(40=<$res<=50)
         {
            echo 'Pass';
         } 
          else  if(01=<$res<=39)
         {
            echo ' Needs Improvement';
         } 
     else  if($res==0)
         {
            echo ' Needs Improvement';
         } 
    </td>
    </tr>
        ";

        break;
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't write if else conditions in the echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$answer = '';
  include('config.php');
  if(isset($_GET["results"]))
 $answer = $_GET["results"];
  $id = $_GET["idk"];
  switch ($answer) 
  {  
    case 'Nursery':
    $qqqs = mysql_query("select * from result where u_id='$id' AND sc='Nursery' ");
    $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($qqqs);
    $a=$rows['u_id'];
    $b=$rows['name'];
    $c=$rows['fname'];
    $d=$rows['reg'];
    $e=$rows['sc'];
    $f=$rows['ss'];
    $g=$rows['se'];
    $h=$rows['e1'];
    $i=$rows['u1'];
    $j=$rows['m1'];
    $k=$rows['s1'];
    $l=$rows['ss1'];
    $m=$rows['i1'];
    $n=$rows['e2'];
    $o=$rows['u2'];
    $p=$rows['e3'];
    $pp=$rows['u3'];
    $pic=$rows['picture'];
    $total=$h+$i+$j+$k+$l+$m+$n+$o+$p;
    $totals=230;

    $res = ( $totals / $total) * 100;

    // 0 digit after the decimal point
    $res = round($res); // 67

    // 1 digit after the decimal point
    $res = round($res, 1); // 66.7

    // 2 digits after the decimal point
    $res = round($res, 2); // 66.67


    $out = "<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <table align='center' border='4' bgcolor='white' width='500' class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor='orange' colspan='4'><h2 align='center'>Leads Grammar School</h2><p align='center'>Babar Road, Kirri Jamandan, Multan</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor='yellow' colspan='4'><h2 align='center'>Monthly Test Feb-March</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan='2'><img src='images/$pic' width='100px' height='100px' align='right'></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Student's Name</td>

    <td colspan='3'>$b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Father's Name</td>
    <td colspan='3'> $c</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Registration</td>
    <td colspan='3'>$d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Student Class</td>
    <td colspan='3'>$e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Exams</td>
    <td colspan='3'>$f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor='gray'>
    <th>Subject Name</th>
    <th>Marks</th>
    <th>Obtained Marks</th>
    <th>Grades</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr><td>English(Writing)</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td> $h</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Urdu(Writing)</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>$i</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Math(Writing)</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td> $j</td>

    </tr>
    <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>General Knowledge</th></tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Science</td>
    <td>10</td>

    <td> $k</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>S.Studies</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$l</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Islamiat</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$m</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>Poems</th></tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>English </td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td> $n</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Urdu</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>$o</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>Book Reading</th></tr>
    <tr>
    <tr><td>English </td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$p</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <tr >
    <td>Urdu</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$pp</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><h1>Total Marks</h1></td>
     <td>230</td>
     <td>$total</td>
     <td>$res</td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td><h2>Remarks</h2></td>
     <td colspan='3'>";

     if(91=<$res<=100)
     {
        $out .= 'Exceptional';
     } 
    else  if(81=<$res<=90)
     {
        $out .= 'Excellent';
     } 
      else  if(71=<$res<=80)
     {
        $out .= 'Very Good';
     } 
      else  if(61=<$res<=70)
     {
        $out .= 'Good';
     } 
      else  if(51=<$res<=60)
     {
        $out .= 'Fair';
     } 
      else  if(40=<$res<=50)
     {
        $out .= 'Pass';
     } 
      else  if(01=<$res<=39)
     {
        $out .= ' Needs Improvement';
     } 
 else  if($res==0)
     {
        $out .= ' Needs Improvement';
     } 
$out .="</td></tr>";
echo $out;
    break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not have support for this syntax:

```
if(01=<$res<=39)
```

Instead you'll have to do this:

```
if(1 <= $res && $res <= 39)
```

Also, don't start your numbers with a 0 or they'll be interpreted as octal numbers (base 8) which will have some strange consequences.

EDIT upon closer inspection

Oh... additionally you indeed cannot have conditional statements inside an echo. You'll have to build the whole string in code first, and *then* echo it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply end your first echo and then use your if statement to echo the remaining of the table.

```
<?php
$answer = '';
  include('config.php');
  if(isset($_GET["results"]))
 $answer = $_GET["results"];
  $id = $_GET["idk"];
  switch ($answer) 
  {  
    case 'Nursery':
    $qqqs = mysql_query("select * from result where u_id='$id' AND sc='Nursery' ");
    $rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($qqqs);
    $a=$rows['u_id'];
    $b=$rows['name'];
    $c=$rows['fname'];
    $d=$rows['reg'];
    $e=$rows['sc'];
    $f=$rows['ss'];
    $g=$rows['se'];
    $h=$rows['e1'];
    $i=$rows['u1'];
    $j=$rows['m1'];
    $k=$rows['s1'];
    $l=$rows['ss1'];
    $m=$rows['i1'];
    $n=$rows['e2'];
    $o=$rows['u2'];
    $p=$rows['e3'];
    $pp=$rows['u3'];
    $pic=$rows['picture'];
    $total=$h+$i+$j+$k+$l+$m+$n+$o+$p;
    $totals=230;

    $res = ( $totals / $total) * 100;

    // 0 digit after the decimal point
    $res = round($res); // 67

    // 1 digit after the decimal point
    $res = round($res, 1); // 66.7

    // 2 digits after the decimal point
    $res = round($res, 2); // 66.67


    echo "<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <table align='center' border='4' bgcolor='white' width='500' class='table table-bordered'>
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor='orange' colspan='4'><h2 align='center'>Leads Grammar School</h2><p align='center'>Babar Road, Kirri Jamandan, Multan</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor='yellow' colspan='4'><h2 align='center'>Monthly Test Feb-March</h2></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan='2'><img src='images/$pic' width='100px' height='100px' align='right'></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Student's Name</td>

    <td colspan='3'>$b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Father's Name</td>
    <td colspan='3'> $c</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Registration</td>
    <td colspan='3'>$d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Student Class</td>
    <td colspan='3'>$e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align='right'>Exams</td>
    <td colspan='3'>$f</td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor='gray'>
    <th>Subject Name</th>
    <th>Marks</th>
    <th>Obtained Marks</th>
    <th>Grades</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr><td>English(Writing)</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td> $h</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Urdu(Writing)</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>$i</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Math(Writing)</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td> $j</td>

    </tr>
    <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>General Knowledge</th></tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Science</td>
    <td>10</td>

    <td> $k</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>S.Studies</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$l</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Islamiat</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$m</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>Poems</th></tr>
    <tr>
    <tr ><td>English </td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td> $n</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <tr ><td>Urdu</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>$o</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><th align='center' colspan='3' bgcolor='orange'>Book Reading</th></tr>
    <tr>
    <tr><td>English </td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$p</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <tr >
    <td>Urdu</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>$pp</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><h1>Total Marks</h1></td>
     <td>230</td>
     <td>$total</td>
     <td>$res</td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td><h2>Remarks</h2></td>
     <td colspan='3'>";
     if(91=<$res<=100)
     {
        echo 'Exceptional';
     } 
    elseif(81=<$res<=90)
     {
        echo 'Excellent';
     } 
      else  if(71=<$res<=80)
     {
        echo 'Very Good';
     } 
      elseif(61=<$res<=70)
     {
        echo 'Good';
     } 
      elseif(51=<$res<=60)
     {
        echo 'Fair';
     } 
      elseif(40=<$res<=50)
     {
        echo 'Pass';
     } 
      else  if(01=<$res<=39)
     {
        echo ' Needs Improvement';
     } 
 elseif($res==0)
     {
        echo ' Needs Improvement';
     } 
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

    break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator for conditions within echo:

```
echo "start of string....".(bool_condition1 ? "condition is true" : "condition is false").".... more string";
```

Comment: Thanks to all ..you solved my problem and best wishes to all of you

Comment: @beginner If my answer helped you, I would greatly appreciate it if you could mark it as "accepted" for others to find later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have if/else conditions in an echo by concatenating:

```
$x = 10;
echo "X is " . ($x==10? "equal" : "not equal") . " to 10";
```

I would also recommend that you create a function that return the string evaluating the score.
Try to mix as little logic as possible with the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `if` statement inside `echo`. What you can do is to move all your `if`'s outside the echo, and store the result in a variable. Eg:

```
if(91 <= $res && $res <= 100) // Note how the condition *should* be written.
{
  $remark = 'Exceptional';
} 
else  if(...
```

and then use the variable in your table output:

```
 <tr><td><h2>Remarks</h2></td>
 <td colspan='3'>$remark
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use ternary operators, in combination with a custom function:

```
echo "fixed part".(inbetween($res,91,100)?'Exceptional':(inbetween($res,81,90)?'Excellent':'SOMETHING ELSE'));

function inbetween($int,$min,$max)
{
   return ($int>=$min && $int<=$max);
}
```

The syntax of this ternary operator can be seen in the following example:

```
echo "This is the result: " . ( $testiftrue ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE' );
```

This will test the condition $testiftrue, and then display 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'